# Google Doubleclick DFP include click macro in an iframe creative

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-dfp

I have an ad served through DFP that is coming from an iframe. I can count impressions, but not clicks (at first clicks were equal to impressions!).

The iframe is currently set up like this in DFP:

```
<iframe  src="http://website.int/dev.php/en/dynamicBanner/728x90" click=%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%% width="728" height="90" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"; " ></iframe>
```

The developer has the click macro appended to the href/URL:

```
<a href="http://website.int/dev.php/en/news/industry-news/info?click=clickmacro" class="inner-item" target="_blank">
```

What has to be changed and where in order to count impressions and clicks properly?